# MySQL 5.5 ignores boolean mode in fulltext search

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I have recently upgraded to MySQL 5.5 (from 5.0). My search is broken now. It won't find most of the search phrases. After a while I noticed, it's possibly the 50% threshold (rare words are found). It's InnoDB. I have already set blank stopwords file in my.cnf.

Those queries are already like this

```
AGAINST (@srch IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Yet many, often all, results are ignored.

The only reason I can think of, is this warning line phpMyAdmin gives upon login:

> Your PHP MySQL library version 5.0.51a differs from your MySQL server
>   version 5.5.22. This may cause unpredictable behavior.

However everything else seem to work just fine. I really can't upgrade php. Also there's pretty big chance it's not the reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: did you check the `ft_min_word_len` ?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty I setup =2 (as it was in 5.0) and restart mysql already. No change.

Comment: Drop the indexes and re-create or do a repair `repair table table_name quick`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty That's what I was also think of but it's InnoDB. Repair table won't work.

Comment: Hmm I guess full text search for innodb is supported from `mysql 5.6`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty That can't be true. It worked just fine in 5.0 before upgrade to 5.5. If the index is the problem and there is no REPAIR for innodb, then I might have to export/import whole database. But I really don't like this solution.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Comment: Full-text searches are supported for InnoDB and MyISAM tables only. FULLTEXT index support for InnoDB tables requires MySQL 5.6.4 or higher. -> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-restrictions.html

Comment: @MarcoMura There is really error in mysql manual. It worked in 5.0 and still works in 5.5. See my own answer. Problem was elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After setting up stopwords and ft_min_word_len, I had to drop the whole InnoDB database (dump & import). Now it works.

As for fulltext search available since 5.6.4: There is some typo/error in official mysql manual. It worked in 5.0 and still works in 5.5. The problem was in rebuilding the index for InnoDB.